# Unable to compile Typescript: property send does not exist on s3client

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk-js

I'm using v3 of the AWS SDK for javascript in a typescript/nodejs environment, but when I run it with ts-node, it complains about being unable to find the send function on the s3client. My code:

```
const client = new S3Client({
  credentialDefaultProvider: this.getCredentialDefaultProvider
  region: "us-west-2",
});
const command = new ListObjectsCommand({
  Bucket: bucket,
  Prefix: prefix,
});
const result = await client.send(command);
```

The error I get when starting my server is this:

```
/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:230
  return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)

TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/controllers/aws.controller.ts(56,37): error TS2339: Property 'send' does not exist on type 'S3Client'.
```

This is basically the same as the code samples in [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/listobjectscommand.html). But I have installed the correct packages (and even cleared my node_modules folder and reinstalled it) and the code in node_modules looks correct. What am I doing wrong?

For context, this is a nodeJS script running in ts-node in a docker-compose container. Other code works fine, including a command to get a signedURL using the same client object.

Comment: S3Client config does not have a credentialDefaultProvider parameter.

Comment: @kevintechie removing that line doesn't fix the compilation issue.

Comment: Have you inspected the client variable? What does TS think it is? Probably need all code to debug further.

Comment: @kevintechie I am getting the same error just running the examples from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-s3 inside a TypeScript file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We got the same error with a fresh (v3.51.0) @aws-sdk\client-s3 module but not with the older v3.47.0.
Downgraded the @aws-sdk\client-s3 module to v3.47.0 and our worries were gone.

Comment: Downgrading @aws-sdk/client-s3 (and @aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner in this particular case) to ~3.47.0 resolved our issue. I have no idea why it would compile fine locally but complain when run with a docker container, but at least the server runs.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3330) seems to track the problem.

Comment: I still have the same problem in `"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.312.0"` :/